# Compiling a C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 created in Linux containing make file

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, visual-studio-2015

I have some C++ projects/programs  which are created in Linux and containing make file as well.
I am using window 7 and visual studio 2015. Today I just installed Ubuntu Linux in virtual box BUT do not really know how to start with and run these programs.
What is the easiest way to run theses projects? 
I am very new in C++ programming so a detailed answer is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work in Visual Studio on Windows a good choice would be Visual C++ for Linux Development (VCLinux) :  [see tutorial here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/)

The tutorial creates a Visual Studio (VS) project that builds with MSBuild (VS's internal build system). However you can also create a makefile project that will build with `make`. MSBuild is easier to work with if you know VS or have an existing VS project, make is more flexible and might be the best choice given an existing makefile. You should try some simple examples and decide which works for you.